# How can I run a method in an exception handler?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have an exception handler that runs when my code crashes, but I also need to send a msg to the server (parse.com) when this happens to let the server know the player has stopped playing,

```
void onUncaughtException(NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"uncaught exception: %@", exception.description);
    [self playerLoggedOut];
}
```

The playerloggedOut line gives the error of undeclared identifier self.

How can I run the playerLoggedOut method when the exception happens?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I run the playerLoggedOut method when the exception happens?

You're not going to be able to start some lengthy process like establishing a network connection and sending a message. Your best strategy might be to save the information and send it when the app starts up again so that the server can update its records or whatever. Alternatively, have the client check in with the server every `t` seconds; if the server doesn't hear from the client within some interval like `2t`, it assumes that the client has stopped functioning.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `self` is unknown, because you are not in a method, but a function. Functions do not run in an object context, therefore do not know self.

As mentioned before by Caleb, you should have a watch dog on server-side that automatically logs a player out, if the server gets no messages from the client for a while (in terms of seconds). To prevent from being logged out automatically, when the user is deactive (but still playing), you can implement a heart beat on the client using an instance of `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, don't try to do expensive things like talk to the Parse server in your exception handler.

In regards to what you are actually trying to achieve, you might want to re-think your architecture.

In the sometimes-connected world of mobile devices you will have your connection come and go. Instead of a boolean flag of `IsLoggedIn`, consider a UTC Date Time of `LastUserActivity`, and use a rule that says they are considered logged in if that last activity is in the last 5 minutes, or whatever is suitable.

If all access to Parse is done via Cloud Code then you could easily add a function call that sets the `LastUserActivity` to each method, then you can also avoid issues with time sync since you'll always be using the server's clock.

If you want to get a list of all online users, you can then just query for where `LastUserActivity` is greater than 5 minutes ago (or whatever limit you set).